Turning dataframe into table in R
I read the excel file shown in the image below into R using the read_excel() from the readxl package. Is there a way for me to turn the data into a table where it counts the number of Locations by Company as shown in the image below? Thanks.
edit:
library(datapasta)
data <- tibble::tribble(
     ~Company, ~Document, ~Location.1, ~Location.2, ~Location.3, ~`Location.4.(City.Specified)`,
     "NVIDIA",      "N1",         "x",          NA,          NA,                             NA,
     "NVIDIA",      "N2",          NA,          NA,         "x",                             NA,
     "NVIDIA",      "N3",          NA,          NA,         "x",                             NA,
     "NVIDIA",      "N4",         "x",          NA,         "x",                             NA,
     "NVIDIA",      "N5",          NA,          NA,          NA,                "Palo Alto, CA",
     "Google",      "G1",          NA,         "x",          NA,                             NA,
     "Google",      "G2",          NA,         "x",          NA,                             NA,
  "Microsoft",      "M1",         "x",          NA,          NA,               "Washington, DC",
      "Tesla",      "T1",          NA,          NA,         "x",                             NA,
      "Tesla",      "T2",         "x",         "x",         "x",                "Princeton, NJ",
      "Tesla",      "T3",          NA,         "x",          NA,                   "Dallas, TX"
  )
head(data)



Hello. You need to transform the table from wide to long format, then you can count the values with dplyr group_by() and summarise()

Hi user, please provide a reprex of your data. It will drastically increase the chances of getting a good answer. There are several ways of providing a sample of your data. You can use dput or datapasta (see: https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/datapasta-reprex.html)

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please do not post code or data in images

One way of going about it would be first summarising the locations 1 to 3 and then merging with the location 4.
data_sum <- data |> 
  group_by(Company) |> 
  summarise(
    # sum by counting times where it is NOT NA. 
    Location.1 = sum(!is.na(Location.1)),
    Location.2 = sum(!is.na(Location.2)), 
    Location.3 = sum(!is.na(Location.3))
  )

data_sum

# A tibble: 4 × 4
  Company   Location.1 Location.2 Location.3
  <chr>          <int>      <int>      <int>
1 Google             0          2          0
2 Microsoft          1          0          0
3 NVIDIA             2          0          3
4 Tesla              1          2          2

data_final <- data |> select(Company, `Location.4.(City.Specified)`) |> 
  filter(!is.na(`Location.4.(City.Specified)`)) |> 
  left_join(data_sum) |> 
  relocate(`Location.4.(City.Specified)`, .after = `Location.3`)

data_final

# A tibble: 4 × 5
  Company   Location.1 Location.2 Location.3 `Location.4.(City.Specified)`
  <chr>          <int>      <int>      <int> <chr>                        
1 NVIDIA             2          0          3 Palo Alto, CA                
2 Microsoft          1          0          0 Washington, DC               
3 Tesla              1          2          2 Princeton, NJ                
4 Tesla              1          2          2 Dallas, TX     


If you then want to have the Y(#) and N(0) formatting, you can apply the following:
data_final |> 
  mutate(
    across(
      .cols = where(is.numeric),
      .fns = ~case_when(
        .x == 0 ~ "No (0)",
        .x  > 0 ~ paste0("Yes (", .x, ")")
      )
    )
  )

# A tibble: 4 × 5
  Company   Location.1 Location.2 Location.3 `Location.4.(City.Specified)`
  <chr>     <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>                        
1 NVIDIA    Yes (2)    No (0)     Yes (3)    Palo Alto, CA                
2 Microsoft Yes (1)    No (0)     No (0)     Washington, DC               
3 Tesla     Yes (1)    Yes (2)    Yes (2)    Princeton, NJ                
4 Tesla     Yes (1)    Yes (2)    Yes (2)    Dallas, TX                   



An approach using reframe and across. Needs a non-NA value per group in variable Location.4. ...
Not sure if you really want the "Y" and "N" in the count part of the data though.
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  reframe(across(matches("Loc.*[123]"), ~ sum(.x %in% "x")), 
          `Location.4.(City.Specified)` = 
           `Location.4.(City.Specified)`[!is.na(`Location.4.(City.Specified)`)],
    .by = Company)
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  Company   Location.1 Location.2 Location.3 `Location.4.(City.Specified)`
  <chr>          <int>      <int>      <int> <chr>                        
1 NVIDIA             2          0          3 Palo Alto, CA                
2 Microsoft          1          0          0 Washington, DC               
3 Tesla              1          2          2 Princeton, NJ                
4 Tesla              1          2          2 Dallas, TX

With counts as character fields including "Y", "N"
df %>% 
  reframe(across(matches("Loc.*[123]"), ~ {res <- sum(.x %in% "x")
          if_else(res > 0, paste0("Y (", res, ")"), paste0("N (", res, ")"))}), 
          `Location.4.(City.Specified)` = 
           `Location.4.(City.Specified)`[!is.na(`Location.4.(City.Specified)`)],
    .by = Company)
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  Company   Location.1 Location.2 Location.3 `Location.4.(City.Specified)`
  <chr>     <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>                        
1 NVIDIA    Y (2)      N (0)      Y (3)      Palo Alto, CA                
2 Microsoft Y (1)      N (0)      N (0)      Washington, DC               
3 Tesla     Y (1)      Y (2)      Y (2)      Princeton, NJ                
4 Tesla     Y (1)      Y (2)      Y (2)      Dallas, TX

